# How to conditionally render a component in Next.js without caching CSS styles?

Tags: css, typescript, caching, next.js

I'm pretty new with **Next.js** and do not fully understand the cache functioning.

Given the following simplified example:

**An index page that renders components `Test1`  or `Test2`, depending whether the current minute is even or odd:**

```
import { Test2 } from '@src/components/test2'
import React from 'react'

const conditionallyChooseComponent = () => {
  const d = new Date()
  if (d.getMinutes() % 2 === 0) return <Test1 />
  else return <Test2 />
}

export default function Home() {
  return <div>{conditionallyChooseComponent()}</div>
}
```

**And having the following components. Test1:**

```
export const Test1 = () => {
  const d = new Date()

  return (
    <div className={`${utilStyles.redContainer}`}>
      <h1>It's {d.toISOString()} and I'm Test1 component. My background should be red</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**And Test2:**

```
export const Test2 = () => {
  const d = new Date()

  return (
    <div className={`${utilStyles.blueContainer}`}>
      <h1>It's {d.toISOString()} and I'm Test2 component. My background should be blue</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**And this CSS:**

```
.redContainer {
  background-color: red;
}

.blueContainer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The background color is being cached when the code is executed by building and serving from the transpiled code. When running with `yarn dev` it is working just fine.

Here is the unexpected result:

[Screenshot with Test1 component being rendered with blue background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU2aY.png)

PS: I made this work with the workaround of using the `getInitialProps` to prevent Next.js from caching anything in that page but, for my real use case that option is not valid because I need the render condition to be calculated in the client side since it will depend on the local date of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Next will automatically cache all static pages that doesn't depends on external data, maybe you can implement useEffect to update your date variable or use a simple state, so it should work the way you expect

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-without-data

Comment: Thanks @user8684881 for taking some time to respond :) 
Unfortunately, I did try using `useEffect` and `useState` but it's still caching.
`export default function Home() {
  const [pair, setPair] = useState(isEven(new Date()))

  useEffect(() => {
    setPair(isEven(new Date()))
  }, [pair])

  if (pair) return <Test1 />
  return <Test2 />
}`
Is that what you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

To make that works, you will need to add some client-side code (via `useEffect`), so the React component updates every minute (or so). Funny enough, this is not as simple as it sounds, and even [Dan Abramov has published a long post explaining why things such as `setInterval` may not work intuitively with React](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) (specifically, with React Hooks).

Assuming you use the custom hook Dan explains in the article above, this should work:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  useInterval(() => {
    // this will update the component's date every second
    setDate(new Date()); 
  }, 1000);

  return <div>{date.getMinutes() % 2 === 0 ? <p>Test 1</p> : <p>Test 2</p>}</div>;
}
```

Observe that your code example only executes the `conditionallyChooseComponent` once, just when Next is trying to server-side rendering your page.